# AutoRefresh Entity and Freezing UI

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, entity-framework, mvvm

I'm using solution from: [AutoRefresh Entity Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233770/AutoRefresh-Entity-Framework-data-using-SQL-Server)

I have a **DataGrid** and other controls (**charts**, etc). I would like to update these controls in real-time. Thanks to this solution, I'm able to do this.

Using this code:

```
TeamLeaderMetrics = New AutorefreshWrapper(Of tbl_Metrics_Employee)((From a In entityconn.tbl_Metrics_TeamLeader Where a.LogDate = Date.Today AndAlso a.EEID = EEID()), entityconn, RefreshMode.StoreWins)
```

Where `TeamLeaderMetrics` is 
`Private _TeamLeaderMetrics As AutoRefreshWrapper(Of tbl_Metrics_Employee)` property, which is my **DataGrid ItemsSource**.

It works, everything is updating. But, the problem is that the UI is freezing.

In `ServiceBrokerUtility` static class dependency-OnChange is using:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DirectCast(Sub() notifyRefresh.OnRefresh(), Action))
```

So I thought it is running in the background, but the UI still freeze.

How can I update my controls without freezing UI in real-time? Should I call this solution in other way than in the **ViewModel** contrustor?

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: `So I thought it is running in the background, but the UI still freeze.` are you?  Time to verify.  Also, `Application.Current.Dispatcher` is the UI thread's dispatcher, and therefore anything you run on it will block the UI.  I don't know what you're invoking on it, but if that takes time, the UI will freeze.

Comment: Well, okay, but Application.Current.Dispatcher is in the solution. I'm running it to update DataGrid and Charts. From the source code:
        `if (notifyRefresh != null)
          System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            (Action)(notifyRefresh.OnRefresh));
      }`
And that's why, I'm asking for help. As when I change it to Task for example it gives me an exception: This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.

Comment: I can't see where you're executing long running code in a background thread.  You can make a simple check by, on execution of your background work, check `Thread.Current.GetApartmentState()` and throw if it is an STA thread.

Comment: I'm executing `TeamLeaderMetrics = New AutorefreshWrapper(Of tbl_Metrics_Employee)((From a In entityconn.tbl_Metrics_TeamLeader Where a.LogDate = Date.Today AndAlso a.EEID = EEID()), entityconn, RefreshMode.StoreWins)` from the ViewModel. My controls are bind to TeamLeaderMetrics. It throws MTA. Thank you